# How to start Selenium Grid and register nodes to Hub using Jenkins

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, selenium-grid

I am trying to start a hub and trying to register nodes to the hub. I can able to do it manually. Is there anyway to configure the same on Jenkins machine.

Comment: You can use selenium-grid's jenkins plugin

Comment: all the steps you are doing manually can be scripted. Just create a jenkins job and paste your shell commands in the "execute shell" box after you click "add build step" in job configuration.

Comment: yep, as per @PatMeeker the 'Pre' and 'Post' build will come in handy for this.